# Reenable 'Visibility' field on FeedItem

Tags: chatter, sobject, visibility

We've been using the 'Visibility' field (the one defined [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm)) on the 'FeedItem' object. These have been removed/changed/hidden somehow -- all of the sudden, we get *"No such column 'Visibility' on entity 'FeedItem'"* when attempting to query for it.

When accessing the 'FeedItem' object through 'Setup -> Search', it has no fields. My line of thinking was that I could somehow reenable/reactivate the field somehow there, but to no avail.

How can we get the 'Visbility' field back in 'FeedItem'?

Comment: Do you have Digital experience enabled in your org?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Yes, I think so - Digital Experience appears in the App Launcher.

Comment: Can you edit the post and share the screenshot what options you are able to see when you search for Digital Experiences in Org